# What is the dot notation in the classnames?

Tags: css

I am using this I am not able to understand what tablesour.tablesour.tablesour-cupcake means.

```
.cupcake-table tablesour.tablesour.tablesour-cupcake > thead > tr {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: An element (tablesour) with all 2 of these classes `tablesour tablesour-cupcake`. See https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/  it has nothing to do with `less`. `<tablesour class="tablesour tablesour-cupcake">` would match that

Comment: This is the extreme basics of CSS. I'd suggest coming to grips with the fundamentals before moving onto LESS and other preprocessors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css selector will apply to the next HTML elements and classes

> given CSS selector

```
 .cupcake-table tablesour.tablesour.tablesour-cupcake > thead > tr {}
```

> HTML elements

```
  <element class="cupcake-table">
      …
        <tablesour class="tablesour tablesour-cupcake">
          <thead>
            <tr>
```

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo I got what I was looking for with your answer..

Comment: @JeevanKishoreM Really happpy it did. Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).